# Kill yarn application by Application-Name

Tags: hadoop-yarn

I want to create a cron to kill a yarn application (Spark) by it application name. But i found thant yarn application -kill needs an application ID. Is there a solution to kill it by application name, or to get the application ID using the application name.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
yarn application -list
```

This will give you a list of the applications, with application ID, running on yarn.

Answer (score 7):

The output of the 'yarn application -list' contains the following information of yarn applications:

- Application-Id
- Application-Name
- Application-Type
- User
- Queue
- State
- Final-State
- Progress
- Tracking-URL

You can list the applications and awk by the required parameter. 
For ex: to list the applications by 'Application-Name'

**yarn application -list | awk '$2 == "APPLICATION_NAME" { print $1 }' > applications_list.txt**

Then you can iterate through the file and kill the applications as below:

`while read p; do
  echo $p
  yarn application -kill $p
done <applications_list.txt`

Answer (score 6):

The same answer as others but with using xargs

```
yarn application -list | awk '$2 == "APPLICATION_NAME" { print $1 }' | xargs yarn application -kill
```